# IllegalStateException in adapter.getview outside loop

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm facing the strangest problem which I've been unable to solve.

I have the following loop which its doing it's job correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
    View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

However it is slow. To improve performance, and because every listItem will have the same size I want to put the first two lines outside the loop. This is how I tried:

```
View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(0, null, mListView);
listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
   height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

However this gives me an exception at the first line:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 0
```

Does anyone have any idea why that is?

Thank you!

Comment: adapterCount == 0. Well it was.

Comment: if the items have all the same height, you don't need the loop. The final height is `adapterCount` times `height`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My idea is to calculate the height once and then multiply it by adapterCount, but the way I'm doing it mysteriously gives me an exception

Comment: @Blackbelt looking at the code I was about to say the same thing!

Comment: But yes, I don't need the loop. Nevertheless the exception occurs *before* the loop

Comment: post the whole stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is totally counter to the entire idea of a listview.  Calling getView like that would force it to create a row view for every row in the list.  That's what listView is meant to avoid.  Worse, you aren't even saving them.  SO you're creating them for no purpose.  This will never perform well, and you shouldn't be doing this at all-  if you think you need to, you're designing your app wrong.

Comment: Is there any other way to set two potentially big ListViews (whose data is fetched from different tables) on top of each other and scroll through them seamlessly like one big listview?

Comment: Don't use two listviews?  Make it one listview.  Remember that not every row of a listview has to have the same type of view, if that was your concern.  You can either combine them all into one adapter, or use an adapter of adapters approach.

Comment: Thank you, I'll rethink my approach